# Complex and real matrix for eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, complete-spaces

This is a short one but: Consider the real matrix $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
7 &3  &-4 \\ 
 -2&-1  &2 \\ 
 6&2  &-3 
\end{pmatrix}$ and let $\beta \in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ be the same matrix but considered as a complex matrix.

**Problem**

with use of a computer program calculate the eigenvalues of the two matrices. i.e $\alpha$ over the real numbers and $\beta$ over the complex numbers.

**Question**

What does this actually mean. They are the same but over different numbers? Is it just the same matrix and thus the same result in this problem but got new rules in different problems where the fact that it is over complex numbers makes a difference? Does it make a difference here?

What does the matrix actually look like - I am thinking it is the same but the fact it is over complex numbers do not matter here.

Comment: there could be roots of a polynomial in $\mathbb C$ that are not in $\mathbb R$, e.g., $f(x)=x^2+1$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner What would the matrix look like then? I am having trouble understanding that it is the same but over complex numbers. I found it to be complex numbers for $A$ in Maple as well.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion whether real matrices can have non-real eigenvalues, as such eigenvalues don't correspond to any real eigenvectors. I suspect that that's what they are referring to.

Comment: @Arthur so $\beta$ is the exact same matrix with the exact same eigenvalues?

Comment: Yup. Except we now allow non-real eigenvalues for $\beta$. (I usually consider it possible for a real matrix to have non-real eigenvalues, but they can't here, because otherwise asking this question is completely strange.)

Comment: @Arthur Okay so when my computer spits out $+i$ and $-i$ and $3$ - These are all values for $\beta$ but we discard the complex values for $\alpha$.

Comment: The way I read the question, yes, that is what they are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of your matrix is
$$-x^3+3x^2-x+3 = -(x-3)(x^2+1)$$
The real root of this polynomial is $3$ which is an eigenvalue for $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
7 &3  &-4 \\ 
 -2&-1  &2 \\ 
 6&2  &-3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix} = 3\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Non-real roots of the polynomial are $\pm i$, which are eigenvalues only for $\beta$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
7 &3  &-4 \\ 
 -2&-1  &2 \\ 
 6&2  &-3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1+i \\ -2i \\ 2
\end{pmatrix} = i\begin{pmatrix}
1+i \\ -2i \\ 2
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}
7 &3  &-4 \\ 
 -2&-1  &2 \\ 
 6&2  &-3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1-i \\ 2i \\ 2
\end{pmatrix} = -i\begin{pmatrix}
1-i \\ 2i \\ 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Note that there are no real nonzero vectors $v$ such that $\alpha v = \pm i v$ so they are not eigenvalues of $\alpha$ in this sense.

Comment: Okay so when my computer spits out $+i$ and $-i$ and $3$ - These are all values for $\beta$ but we discard the complex values for $\alpha$.

Comment: @bymathformath Yes, pretty much.

Comment: Must say it is a strange concept for me that they are suddently not values for the one but only for the other matrix.

Comment: @bymathformath Let $V$ be a vector space over $\F$. An eigenvalue for a linear map $A : V\to V$ is an element $\lambda \in \F$ such that there exists a nonzero vector $v\in V$ such that $Av=\lambda v$.